# Muting a bell with a resonating object

Tags: kinematics, spring, resonance

I recently moved into an apartment next to a church with bells and since then I haven't stopped dreaming of ways to mute them. I've been thinking about a design but I'm a little unsure of the feasibility and physics.

The idea is make a hollow cylinder (puck) with a smaller solid puck attached to a spring inside of the hollow one. It would look something like this rough sketch below and would be attached to the inside of the bell.

[image: Bell Muter]

The idea is that the puck would resonate at exactly the opposite frequency of the bell causing the noise to null out. So given a bell of mass M and frequency F what would the spring constant K and mass of the puck need to be to effectively mute the bell?

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't work. Bells resonate at many different frequencies and your wolf tone eliminator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_tone) will only work on one of them effectively (if at all)... so no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CuriousOne wrote, the device will lack frequencies ( and power )

The general solution is to evaluate the efficiency of [Time reversal signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_reversal_signal_processing).

If

- the bell ringing is , each time it is processed ,  identical ( rarely true )
- the aerology between the bell and you is each time identical
- you are able to record **all the** sound and to reproduce it backwards at the **same power**. Heavy devices needed ; read the 'Overview' of the linked page about other difficulties
- you are able to anticipate the bell , ie with an optical signal

you have a chance to reach your goal.

But these conditions aren't fulfilled with this bell ; it would be better to try classical [soundproofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundproofing) solutions.